# How to update my ContentProvider?

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider

I'm using MOTODEV and I create my contentProvider from Motodev. Now I want to add one column in my table. How to do this?

I try implement onUpgrade() in my DbOpenHelper but don't work.

```
     String upgradeQuery = "ALTER TABLE [my_table] ADD COLUMN [my_column] TEXT;";
     if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2)
        db.execSQL(upgradeQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have that exact command in my app (except for the ";" character at the end) and it works, did you remember to set the new version as 2 on your manifest? It's the "version code" field ("android:versionCode").